# Is it possible to get weaker despite weight gain?

Tags: bench-press

Training about 1 years overall. Following a 3 day ppl split. Gained 3 kgs (from 61 - 64) over the last 3 weeks but bench press went from 60 kg to 50kg.

I'm tracking calories religiously, eat 2x protein per kg, and I have a PT checking my form. My sleep hasn't been great but I didn't expect it to completely shatter my performance

How am I getting weaker when gaining weight?

Comment: Performance goes in cycles (and poor sleep can have an impact). There's no way to know what factors may be involved without details (and even then it's hit-or-miss). I'd look back over the training logs over a double period and see if anything significant has changed.

Comment: Tangentially related: self-talk matters. Your brain, body, and spirit listen to what you say.

Comment: Yeah the sleep probably fu**ed it up. It is so frustrating when you try to do everything right and everything goes colossally wrong because of things outside of your control. So angry at myself for basically gaining 3kg of fat AND losing muscle. I'm probably the first person in history to consciously achieve this hahahah

Comment: Unlikely  Not saying it's definitely sleep, but recovery is hugely important, not just for strength gains.

Comment: I agree with Dave's first sentence; performance goes in cycles. What happens in a 3-week period is rarely cause for concern. It's too short of a timespan to make any reasonable conclusion about the trajectory of your progress. Every upward trajectory has dips (no pun intended).

Comment: Also, when lifts start sliding, it may be you need to move your training around a bit, do a week or so of light lifting. You may be overtrained.

Comment: What time frame are we talking here? I know you said 3 weeks, but is the above based on measuring once, then again 3 weeks later, or continual measurement over a year or measuring once a week? It's entirely possible you had an off day caused by lack of sleep, poor hydration, stress and whatever else happened the previous couple of days. You could go in after a good nights sleep and smash your previous PR. Don't judge overall progress on a single bad day.

Comment: @Alec "What happens in a 3-week period is rarely cause for concern". In this case, *it is cause for concern*. A kilogram per week of weight gain is *alarmingly fast*.

Comment: `@Thomas yeap I think most of it was estorgen fat gain from lack of sleep. Faak